# bash how to selectively remove space in a string

Tags: bash

Is there a way to selectively remove spaces in a string, in bash?
e.g.

```
hello world你好 世界！
hello world你 好 世 界！
hello world 你 好 世 界！
你 好 世 界 hello world
```

and output:

```
hello world你好世界！
你好世界hello world
```

Notice I want to preserve spaces between English words or simply English alphabet, but not the others.

I understand `python.re` module is probably good for this, but i prefer a bash command if possible.

Comment: According to [this table](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/character_classes/std_char_classes.html), the Kanji should be matched in bash by `[[ $var =~ [[:unicode:]] ]]`, and based on this, you could build up an iterative solution. However, I found that in my bash at least, this match does not work (although I have set `LANG` to be unicode. I don't know why this does not work. Maybe you could factor out a separate question in Stackoverflow from this, i.e. _how to do a regex match in bash on characters with unicode code point above 255_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
echo hello world你好 世界！ | sed -E "s/([^a-zA-Z]) ([^a-zA-Z])/\1\2/g"
```

- `([^a-zA-Z]) ([^a-zA-Z])` is a regular expression matching a whitespace between two non latin characters (`^` negates). The preceding and following characters are captured in groups (#1 and #2)
- `\1\2` is the replacement string (only groups without whitespace in-between)

Output:

```
hello world你好世界！
```

Note: to replace starting and trailing whitespaces, your expression should be:

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z]) ([^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Edit: One thing I didn't take into account is that this kind of expression consumes the characters before and after the whitespaces. So in the case `你 好 世 界 hello world` a whitespace was still remaining. You then have to use a regex engine that supports lookarounds:

```
echo " 你 好 世 界 hello world, !"  | perl -pe "s/(?<=^|[^[:ascii:]]) | (?=[^[:ascii:]]|$)//g"
```

Output:

```
你好世界hello world
```

In order to remove space between latin chars/kandji I split the expression in two. I also replaced the condition on latin character with ascii. Should give more appropriate matches

Comment: `sed` looks like a solid way, but this is not yet handling other cases like "hello world你 好 世 界！". It gives me "hello world你好 世界" on OSX (BSD sed).

Comment: @galactica Try `g` instead of `p`?

Comment: still seeing an extra space between "你好 世界", yeah, it's strange that `g` doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: @Shawn is right! depending on how you plan to use it, you probably don't need the p. and the g should replace all occurrences (edited my answer)

Comment: @Tranbi : This does not work on strings such as `xxx:  ,yyyy`. According to your solution, the spaces would be removed here. I think a correct approach would be to distinguish between unicode characters below and above 255.

Comment: This is true! Maybe `(?<=^|[^[:ascii:]]) (?=[^[:ascii:]]|$)` would better fit OP's need?

Comment: that look-around trick is really cool! too bad `sed` doesn't support it. For my purposes I actually look for a result of "你好世界hello world", i.e., no space during script transition, so i extended your snippet a bit to support that. It handles most cases in a very noisy corpus really well, with a couple of edgy cases left, which is ok.

Comment: Alright! I edited my answer according to @user1934428's feedback and yours. What are the remaining cases where the updated solution doesn't work?

Comment: @Tranbi : Where is `[:ascii:]` documented? I didn't find it [here](https://relishapp.com/jarhart/rattler/docs/extended-matching-syntax/posix-character-classes), but this site is not authoritative. However I haven't found it in other sites on this topic either?

Comment: @user1934428 you can find it in the [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref#CHARACTER-CLASSES) but to be honest I probably found it first somewhere on SO... BTW your link does mention ascii, the example is simply missing

Comment: @Tranbi: perldoc does not help, because bash (AFIK) does not implement Perl RE (PCRE). It implements POSIX extended regular expressions, which are different.

Comment: @user1934428 That's true that [:ascii:] (and [:word:], see this [regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)) are not supported by all regex flavors. But my updated answer (see Edit) does use perl... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tranbi : Ah, right, I glanced only over the `sed` solution. I agree that in this case, something like Perl (or Ruby, or Python) is perhaps a safe solution. IMO, your solution should work, though my Perl (5.32.1) gives the warning _Variable length lookbehind is experimental in regex_. Still, I just wonder why we can't handle this seemingly simple case completely within the extended regexp supported by bash, without reverting to a child process....

Comment: Sorry I made a lot of edits to my answer which made it hard to follow. I originally switched to perl because of lookarounds. I also underestimated the problem at the beginning thinking sed would solve it easily...

Comment: few cases left out like "meet at 4:00 PM" -> "meet at 4:00 PM" (expecting "meet at 4:00PM", "make sure 500 G B is used" -> "make sure 500 G B is used" (expecting "make sure 500 GB is used"). As I mentioned this is a noisy corpus and to fix those cases is beyond what regex could do.

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution using Unicode properties (In particular, if a character is or isn't in the [latin script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode):

```sh
$ perl -CSD -lpe 's/^\s+//; # Remove leading spaces
                  s/\s+$//; # Remove trailing spaces
                  # Remove spaces between two non-latin characters.
                  s/(\P{scx=Latin})\s++(?=\P{scx=Latin})/$1/g; 
                  # Remove spaces between a leading latin and trailing non-latin
                  s/(\p{scx=Latin})\s++(?=\P{scx=Latin})/$1/g;
                  # Remove spaces between a leading non-latin and trailing latin
                  s/(\P{scx=Latin})\s++(?=\p{scx=Latin})/$1/g;' input.txt
hello world你好世界！
hello world你好世界！
hello world你好世界！
你好世界hello world
```

It does a bunch of substitutions for the different cases where you want to remove spaces instead of trying to use a single regular expression to match every possibility.

Comment: Depending on your actual text, using ASCII vs non-ASCII might work better, as things like punctuation characters aren't in the Latin script (They're in Common). `[[:ascii:]]` and `[^[:ascii:]]` if so instead of `\p{scx=Latin}` and `\P{scx=Latin}`.

Comment: haven't touched perl's regex for a while but this is clearly structured out there, thanks!